# React state not updated correctly when using useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I have this example code. I have a state urls which I create using useState hook. I have initialized urls state to empty array. I have another array arr. For each item in arr, I am pushing that item to urls state. When I render contents of urls, only last item pushed is displayed. It seems while updating urls, only last update is taking effect. What could be wrong?

```
function Hi() {
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);

  let arr = ["hi", "hello"];

  React.useEffect(() => {

    arr.forEach(item => {
      let url_list = [...urls];
      url_list.push(item);
      setUrls(url_list)
    })

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
     {urls.map(item => (
        <Text>{item}</Text>
     ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the state in each interaction of the array.

The problem here is that setState is asynchronous ([read](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)), i.e the update doesn't happen instantly. In other words, when you do `let url_list = [...urls]`, on the second and last iteraction, urls is still [], so that's why you're only getting "hello" into it.

You have 2 main approachs in this case:

**1. Update the state after you've mapped the entire array.**

```
React.useEffect(() => { 
  let url_list = [...urls]

  arr.forEach(item => {
    url_list.push(item);
  })

  setUrls(url_list)

}, []);
```

**2. Since setState returns the previous state ([read](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)), you can do something like this:**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   
  arr.forEach(item => {
    let url_list = [...urls];
    url_list.push(item);
    setUrls(prevUrls => ([...prevUrls, ...url_list]))
  })
        
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `url_list` inside forEach. This is reset the values inside url_list on each iterations. Declare url_list outside of forEach and it should be working